# Stuck with a proof

Tags: coq

I'm fairly new to Coq, and was doing some Katas on CodeWars for fun and learning.

I'm stuck with one of them and want to hear some ideas from you.

So, I have:

```
Record iso (A B : Set) : Set :=

bijection {

A_to_B : A -> B;

B_to_A : B -> A;

A_B_A : forall a : A, B_to_A (A_to_B a) = a;

B_A_B : forall b : B, A_to_B (B_to_A b) = b

}.


(* nat_plus_nat : a set having size(nat) more elements than nat. (provided in preloaded) *)
Inductive nat_plus_nat : Set := left (n : nat) | right (n : nat).


Theorem nat_iso_natpnat : iso nat nat_plus_nat.
```

I have and idea, but I can't implement it, and I don't know if it's feasible. Basically, I want to map every odd nat to one constructor(left, for example) and every even nat to another(right, for example). Will this work? If no, how can it be done?

Right now I'm stuck with the fact, that `A_to_B` defined as `fun n => if odd n then left n else right n` and `B_to_A` defined as `fun n => match n with | left n' => n' | right n' => n' end` won't give me enough facts to eliminate some cases.

Comment: What's `A_to_B (B_to_A (left 2))`?

Comment: Yep, you guessed it right, it's not a `left 2`, but `right 2`, or, in other words, this 2 functions aren't forming a bijection.

Comment: A hint/reminder that may make it easier to think about the problem is that bijective functions must be both injective (they don't map two elements to the same image) and surjective (all elements in the codomain of each function must have an antecedent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the math correctly first: find two functions that are inverse of each other.

You initial intent is correct: odd numbers to one side, even numbers to the other side, but what you store on each side should cover all the natural numbers, so you will probably have to divide by 2 somewhere.

For Coq usage, You should load the `Arith` package, by starting with the following line:

```
Require Import Arith.
```

This way, you can benefit from existing functions, like `Nat.div2`  and `Nat.even` and all the existing theorems about them.  To find the relevant theorems, I suggest commands like:

```
Search Nat.even 2.
Search Nat.div2.
```

Last hint: proving properties of `Nat.div2` by induction is rather difficult for beginners.  Try to use the existing theorems as much as possible.  If you choose to perform a proof by induction concerning `div2`, go look in the sources in file `theories/Arith/Div2.v`  : the author of that file designed a specific induction theorem called `ìnd_0_1_SS` just for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you, your hint with dividing by two helped me greatly!